# Azure B2C : Asp.Net Web API calling Asp.Net Web.API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have two Web API services (source & target).  Each are registered with Azure B2C as AD applications using client secrets.

I am attempting to invoke a gRPC API call from the source service to the target service API however when I attempt to make the call I am gRPC exception that says the source is unauthenticated.

Note: When I remove the Scope Policy and Authorized attributes from the target WebAPI all works fine but of course this is not secure.

In the source service startup I have the following...

Note: the configuration settings are correct for both source and target. I've triple checked all config settings are correct.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    },
    options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
    });
```

I am not sure if it's required but I also included the following logic in the source API's start up.

> Note: I've hard coded the required scopes for now.

```cs
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C")
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "https://nextwaredev.onmicrosoft.com/nextware.productportal.sharedservices.api/sharedservices_readaccess", "https://nextwaredev.onmicrosoft.com/nextware.productportal.sharedservices.api/sharedservices_readwriteaccess" })
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

The target service has the correct Policies and both services are configured to use Authorization and Authentication..

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I have added the API permissions that are required to the source based upon the same scopes from above..

[image]

When I attempt the invoke a method on the target API, I get back a gRPC exception that says the source is unauthenticated.

So then I thought perhaps I need to pass in an Application Access Token however when I try to acquire the JWT access token (following [this example](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/daemon-scenarios)  calling tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForAppAsync) I get another exception "AADB2C90086: The supplied grant_type [client_credentials] is not supported."

Note:  I have a Blazor application that has no issues invoking the same secured API's.  However there I call GetAccessTokenForUserAsync... which returns the proper token with applied scopes necessary to invoke the same downstream source or target web api services.

Am I required to include the AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication at startup?
What else am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your assistance!
Cheers

Comment: COuld you please tell me how you call target API

Answer (score 6):

I could not get client credential flow working using **Microsoft Identity Web Api** directly from Azure B2C so instead I followed this excellent guidance by @Hossam Barakat per [this link](https://www.hossambarakat.net/2020/08/14/azure-b2c-client-credentials/)

I ended with two Authentication types, one that allows for Web API => Web API communication utilizing **Jwt Bearer** while the other used by Web APP => Web API that utilizes the

- List item

**Microsoft Identity Web Api** ...

```
        var authority = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Configuration["AzureAdB2C:TenantId"];
        var validIssuer = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Configuration["AzureAdB2C:TenantId"] + @"/v2.0";
        var audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
        var validAudience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

        .AddJwtBearer("APIToAPI", options =>
           {
               options.Audience = audience;
               options.Authority = authority;
               options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
               {
                   ValidAudience = validAudience,
                   ValidIssuer = validIssuer
               };
           }
        )

        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
               {
                   Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                   options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
               }
               , options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                },
                jwtBearerScheme: "AppToAPI"
        );
```

Then to enable both schemes I had to add the following...

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().AddAuthenticationSchemes("APIToAPI", "APPToAPI").Build();
        }
```

I also added the following Authorize attribute to the controller actions...

```
 [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "APIToAPI, APPToAPI")]
```

The token creation for each type is different.

This is what I use to acquire the access token for the currently authenticated user within a Web APP, calling into an API ...

```
 private static string GetAccessTokenForUser(List<string> scopes)
    {
        if (scopes != null)
        {
            var container = ContainerLocator.Current.Container;

            var configuration = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>();

            var httpContextAccessor = container.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            if (httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
            {
                var tokenService = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();
                try
                {
                    return Task.Run(() => tokenService.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes)).Result;
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error(ex, "error while loading token for current user, try to login again");
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

This is what I use to get the access token when it's a Web API calling into a Web API...

```
public static async Task<TokenResponse> GetAccessTokenAsync(string scope)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var container = ContainerLocator.Current.Container;
        var configuration = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>();

        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + configuration["AzureAdB2C:Domain"] +@"/oauth2/v2.0/token",
            ClientId = configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientSecret"],
            Scope = scope
        });

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return tokenResponse;
    }
```

If an access token is acquired it is simply added to the request header prior to the invocation of the gRPC and or REST API method.

I hope this helps others.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a way of getting back claims in the access token?

Comment: Do you have a repo for this?